# Polymer Ripple Animation on div for on-click - sharedElement Error

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.1

I have a div and on a click I would like to make a colored ripple effect(kind of like the `paper-tab` effect) when pressed.

I am using `ripple-animation` but I get an error `ripple-animation: sharedElement with id undefined not found in <portfolio-display class=​"x-scope portfolio-display-0" style=​"opacity:​ 0;​">​…​</portfolio-display>​` `

According to the docs, I am ether supposed to put `this` or `gesture`. I am not sure what `sharedElement` is or what I am supposed to put. Anyone know?

```
 <template>
    <section>
      <div on-click="buttonPressed"
        class="vertical layout">
        <div>
          <div>
            <h2 class="section-title">Portfolio</h2>
            <p class="section-description">Blah<br>Blah</p>
          </div>
          <div class="layout horizontal center-center">
             <iron-icon class="big" icon="http"></iron-icon>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "portfolio-display",
      behaviors: [
        Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior,
        Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
      ],
      properties: {
        animationConfig: {
          value: function() {
            return {
              'pressAnimation': [{
                name: 'opaque-animation',
                node: this
              }, {
                name: 'fade-out-animation',
                node: this,
                timing: {
                  duration: 0
                }
              }, {
                name: 'ripple-animation',
                id: this,
                toPage: this,
                fromPage: this
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      buttonPressed: function() {
        console.log('sssss');
        this.playAnimation('pressAnimation');
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for such complications, you should just use [paper-ripple](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-ripple?view=demo:demo/index.html) or even [paper-button](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button?view=demo:demo/index.html).

FYI the ripple-animation that you are trying to use is meant for implementing transition effects between pages, via the neon-animated-pages component, and has no other purpose.